# Get video duration of file hosted on Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm starting a portal which distributes videos. The idea is to upload the videos to Amazon S3 and gather the necessary data using PHP from my server. So far everything works fine... the only thing I could not manage to get is the duration of the video :-( Could anybody give me a hint on how to accomplish it?

Thanks,
Miguel

UPDATE:

I finally opted to do it using FFmpeg. I have already installed FFmpeg on the server and I'm now trying to execute the command in the shell prior to execute it with PHP. I'm passing it the URL from Amazon (I tried both the cloudfront URL and the S3 URL) but it says that there is not such a directory or file. I've seen examples on the web using external files so I expected it to work.

The command I'm using is

```
ffmpeg -i https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.m4v
```

Is there something I need to configure in order to use external URLs?

Comment: If you are using a video player you can usually pull the information that way.  What type of video is it?

Comment: It's a flv encoded video. The idea is to display the duration on the listings page and it will also be used for searching so I need to save that data in my database.

Comment: I would use my jwplayer to pull the info from the file in javascript, then perhaps pass that back to php using AJAX.

Comment: That doesn't sound very clean :-( If JWPlayer can do it, it should be possible to be done using PHP as well. I might need to install FFmpeg on the server to get the info, but I hoped that the S3 API could provide me that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a sample code snippet from LongTail which uses PHP and FFMPeg
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/9448/how-to-get-video-duration-with-ffmpeg-and-php

Seems to be another solution here:
http://www.jqueryphp.com/getting-video-duration-with-ffmpeg-php-function/2009/10/

You'll need FFMpeg installed on your server

Comment: Thanks Steven. My video files are quite large (400-600MB)... do you know if FFmpeg can access them remotely and get the neccesary data without the need of downloading the whole file?

Comment: Surely you have the video file stored locally, at least temporarily, while you're uploading it to S3? You should be able to get the duration then. Failing that, use ffmpeg once to determine the length and store that in your database.

Comment: Hi... The file will be uploaded directly to S3 without passing through our server... but it seems that I will have to change my idea and have it pass through it to retrieve the duration.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use FFmpeg (or can't install it on your server) another option is to look for the duration in the video file's embedded metadata.

It is usually stored in one or more tags called "Duration" or "PlayDuration".

You can read the embedded metadata from the video file using something like [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) and then parse the output for the tags.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my code will help someone getting S3 video file duration. If you see no metadata (using getMetadata() method provided by FilesystemInterface) you need to install ffmpeg on your machine/server. Then install this package: https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

Now, I'll provide you with my code. It's not the best, as I need to run it as a command, only once.

```html
public static function getVideoDurationInMilliseconds(?string $path): ?float
    {
        if ($path === null) {
            return null;
        }

        // Basically you need only something like this
        // videos/s/jtr40wdcmc/teflon_vs_velcro.mp4
        $filePath = str_replace('https://YOUR_S3_USER-userprofiles.s3.YOUR_REGION.amazonaws.com/', '', $path);

        ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); // this code is really memory exhaustive

        $localStorage = \Storage::disk('local');
        $s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
        $ffProbe = FFProbe::create();
        try {
            $contents = $s3->assertExists($filePath)
                ->get($filePath);
            $fileName = $s3->getMetadata($filePath)['basename'];
            $localStorage->put($fileName, $contents);
            $durationInSeconds = $ffProbe->format($localStorage->path($fileName))
                ->get('duration');
            $localStorage->delete($fileName);
        } catch (ExpectationFailedException $ex) {
            \Log::alert('File with path: ' . $filePath . ' does not exists on S3.', [$ex]);
            return null;
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            \Log::alert('Could not process S3 file: ' . $filePath, [$ex]);
        }

        return is_numeric($durationInSeconds)
            ? ((float) $durationInSeconds) * 1000
            : null;
    }
```

Code takes file from S3, saves locally, checks duration using ffmpeg package and then removes file. You can run it over any loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is an another possible solution.
You will need to set the object metadata when you put the video file into the S3 bucket.

In order to set user metadata on an object, prefix the header values with 'x-amz-meta-'.